# How to get start and end date of a specific quarter

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, date

I'm looking to update the start date & end date of the specific quarter based on the year and quarter fields selected by the end user. I thought of trying with the Period object but I'm unable to filter quarters by FullyQualifiedLabel.  #Flow #Apex #Quarter Filter. How to achieve this in Flow

For Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no proper native support for this in Flow, so you will have to revert to APEX to help you.

Luckily [Carl Vescovi](https://www.linkedin.com/in/carlvescovi/) has already done that for you:

https://unofficialsf.com/flow-datetime-methods/

You could use the `addMonths` function to get to the first month of the quarter, and the use `toStartOfMonth()` function to get to the first day. For getting to the last day of the quarter, use `addDays(-1)` from the first day of the next quarter.